# Failing when try catch data from kafka brokers inside a docker swarm

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-swarm

I am working in a infrastructure with docker swarm where have one (and only) kafka per node, everything up's ok, without any error/warn log, but when I try access the second broker (`worker2`) I catch error. Take a look on the output:

```
kafkacat -L -b worker2:9094                                                                                                                     
% ERROR: Failed to acquire metadata: Local: Timed out
```

The expected output from `worker1` is:

```
kafkacat -L -b worker1:9094                                                                                                                      
Metadata for all topics (from broker 1001: worker1:9094/1001):
 2 brokers:
  broker 1001 at worker1:9094
  broker 1002 at worker2:9094
 1 topics:
  topic "logging_application_access" with 1 partitions:
    partition 0, leader 1001, replicas: 1001, isrs: 1001
```

Output from my list nodes is:

```
ID                            HOSTNAME            STATUS              AVAILABILITY        MANAGER STATUS      ENGINE VERSION
c6msb82zav2p1lepd13phmeei *   manager1            Ready               Active              Leader              18.06.1-ce
n3sfqz4rgewtulz43q5qobmr1     worker1             Ready               Active                                  18.06.1-ce
xgkibsp0kx29bhmjkwysapa6h     worker2             Ready               Active                                  18.06.1-ce
```

For better understood, take a look at my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.6'

x-proxy: &proxy
  http_proxy: ${http_proxy}
  https_proxy: ${https_proxy}
  no_proxy: ${no_proxy}

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: zookeeper:3.4.13
    hostname: zookeeper
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: zookeeper-data
        target: /data
    environment:
      <<: *proxy
    ports:
      - target: 2181
        published: 2181
        protocol: tcp
    networks:
      - workshop
    restart: always
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == worker

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:2.12-2.1.0
    hostname: kafka
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: kafka-data
        target: /kafka
      - type: bind
        source: /var/run/docker.sock
        target: /var/run/docker.sock
        read_only: true
    env_file: ./services/kafka/.env
    environment:
      <<: *proxy
    ports:
      - target: 9094
        published: 9094
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    networks:
      - workshop
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    deploy:
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == worker

volumes:
  zookeeper-data:
    driver: local
  kafka-data:
    driver: local

networks:
  workshop:
    name: workshop
    external: true
```

And finally the environment file:

```
HOSTNAME_COMMAND=docker info | grep ^Name: | cut -d ' ' -f 2

KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://_{HOSTNAME_COMMAND}:9094
KAFKA_LISTENERS=INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://:9094
KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=INSIDE

KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MS=36000
KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS=36000

KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_HOURS=24
KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE=false
KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS=logging_application_access:1:1

KAFKA_JMX_OPTS=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1099
JMX_PORT=1099
```

I am researching for a solution for this, at this moment without any success.

Comment: I test another configuration changing the `HOSTNAME_COMMAND=docker info | grep 'Node Address:' | cut -d ' ' -f 4`, but without success.

Comment: I don't think the `HOSTNAME_COMMAND` works inside of an environment file. Besides, the [confluent docker compose examples](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/blob/5.1.0-post/examples/cp-all-in-one/docker-compose.yml) work out of the box with the listeners, but you can also read this blog for more info for diagnosing your network issues - https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/ Note: Vagrant would also need a port mapping if your clients are trying to connect to the VM, which is running Docker Swarm...

Comment: @cricket_007 `HOSTNAME_COMMAND` works fine inside env file without quotes. I will read your references. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you scale zookeeper down to one instance, does it start working? In my experience, if you want to run zookeeper in High Availability mode, you need to explicitly list the whole quorum in the zookeeper connect string, which doesn't work great with a replicated service in docker. So either run only one zookeeper node, or make separate services for each one (i.e. zookeeper1 zookeeper2, zookeeper3) in your compose file and list them all in the zookeeper connect variable, i.e. KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper1:2181,zookeeper2:2181,zookeeper3:2181.

You could try the tasks.zookeeper dnsrr address, but my experience was that didn't get resolved correctly to the list of containers behind the service.

FYI, you don't get any benefit from running two zookeeper nodes; Zookeeper needs more than half of the nodes in the quorum to be up, so you need at least three to have any fault tolerance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, not works as expected. Continues with the issue.

Comment: What if you set your interbroker protocol to OUTSIDE? I think when you ask a non-leader broker for metadata, it talks to the leader. It could be that your brokers are only registering in zookeeper using the external hostnames, and dns lookups on the internal docker network are failing. That would explain why querying the leader (worker1) works.